# OpenShift Error: CLIENT_ERROR: WSGI application was not found

Tags: openshift

After restarting my application, I'm getting this error:

`CLIENT_ERROR: WSGI application was not found`

I ran `find -name *wsgi*` and found this:

`./python/template/wsgi.py`

I'm new to OpenShift. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm using a Django app and Python 3.3, Web Load Balancer, and PostgreSQL 9.2 cartridges if that helps. I tried both the `ctl_all restart` and `ctl_app restart` commands with no luck.

Comment: the `./python/template/wsgi.py` is the default app that is there when you initially create your application. Check to see what's in `./app-root/runtime/repo`

Comment: After running `ls` command I have these: `index.html  python  README.md`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran the `rhc app create <your_app_name> <your_cartridge (e.g. python-3.3)>`command. When the command finishes executing you will have an Apache HTTP server
with mod_wsgi running in the cloud. It will have a public URL, which will have the form
`http://<your_app>-<namespace>.rhcloud.com`. It will also have a private Git repository that
has been cloned to your local machine, in a directory with the same name as your
application.